# No virtual method getBaseContext()Landroid/content/Context #litho

Tags: android-ndk, picasso, android-glide, litho, facebook-litho

## litho

Error

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
>   getBaseContext()Landroid/content/Context; in class
>   Lcom/facebook/litho/ComponentContext; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.facebook.litho.ComponentContext' appears in
>   /data/app/com.midhilaj.myapplication-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

My code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ComponentContext context = new ComponentContext(this);

        Component component2     =GlideImage.create(context)
                 .imageUrl("https://d2b41ce3jhhjt0.cloudfront.net/uploads/social/posts/medium/c57365ec934af9814503ae2de8d252e9.jpg")
                //  .aspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                .centerCrop(true)
                .build();
        setContentView(LithoView.create(context, component2));








 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl>: java.lang.LinkageError: Method java.lang.String com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl.getSimpleName() overrides final method in class Lcom/facebook/litho/Component; (declaration of 'com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl' appears in /data/app/com.midhilaj.myapplication-Aet8ZQAr7vjva0PZdq2jhg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$Builder com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage.create(com.facebook.litho.ComponentContext) (PicassoImage.java:170)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void com.midhilaj.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:45)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6984)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1235)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2857)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2986)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1671)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:108)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:206)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6784)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.996 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.997 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (Zygote.java:240)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.997 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication I/zygote64:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:852)
2019-02-06 17:04:05.997 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-02-06 17:04:06.000 12850-12850/com.midhilaj.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.midhilaj.myapplication, PID: 12850
    java.lang.LinkageError: Method java.lang.String com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl.getSimpleName() overrides final method in class Lcom/facebook/litho/Component; (declaration of 'com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl' appears in /data/app/com.midhilaj.myapplication-Aet8ZQAr7vjva0PZdq2jhg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage.create(PicassoImage.java:170)
        at com.midhilaj.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)
```

Now i am trying with picasso

> java.lang.LinkageError: Method java.lang.String
>   com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl.getSimpleName()
>   overrides final method in class Lcom/facebook/litho/Component;
>   (declaration of
>   'com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage$PicassoImageImpl'
>   appears in
>   /data/app/com.midhilaj.myapplication-zt-xfqQ6-UlHEkWlTDfqyg==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage.create(PicassoImage.java:170)
>           at com.midhilaj.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6984)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1235)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1671)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:206)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6784)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:852)

Comment: `ComponentContext#getBaseContext()` method was replaced with `ComponentContext#getAndroidContext()` a while ago. Could you provide the entire stack of the crash?

Comment: updated please check it

Answer (score 0):

Neither `com.github.charbgr.litho.picasso.PicassoImage` nor `GlideImage` is a part of Litho framework. You probably should try updating the libraries that provide those classes. Or, if they haven't been updated to work with newer versions of Litho, pull back to using the older versions of the framework, that those libraries are still compatible with. Although, latter seems like a bad idea to me